# My program crashes when using free function (C) on array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free, jagged-arrays

My program works if I don't free the memory I allocated dinamically, but when I try to free it, it crashes. I am running my code on Dev-C++ and the error message is not helpful: a problem has made the program stop working.
The problem is at the end of the code. If I take of the freeing part, the program works just fine. Here is a sample input:

```
5
2.3
1.4 8.2
3.1 2.0 7.7
5.3 6.1 4.4 1.2
5.5 6.1 3.0 2.3 4.9
```

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void) {
    int ordem;
    scanf("%d", &ordem);
    double **vetor; //apontador para apontador (jagged array)
    double soma = 0;
    int elementos;
    elementos = (ordem*ordem + ordem) / 2;
    vetor = malloc(ordem * sizeof(double*));   //o primeiro endereço do vetor é seu local de memória, que define quantos pointers ele terá (ordem)
    int n, m;
    for (n = 0; n < ordem; n++) {
        *(vetor + n) = malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    }
    for (n = 0; n < ordem; n++) {
        for (m = 0; m <= n; m++) {
            scanf("%lf", *(vetor + n) + m);
            soma = soma + *(*(vetor + n) + m);
        }
    }
    double media = soma / (double) elementos;
    double aux = 0;
    for (n = 0; n < ordem; n++) {
        for (m = 0; m <= n; m++) {
            aux = aux + pow((media - vetor[n][m]), 2);
        }
    }
    double desvio = sqrt(aux / ((double)elementos));
    for (n = 0; n < ordem; n++) {
        for (m = 0; m <= n; m++) {
            printf("%.12lf ", (vetor[n][m] - media) / desvio);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n%.12lf %.12lf \n", media, desvio);

    for (n = 0; n < ordem; n++) {
        free(*(vetor + n));
    }
    free(vetor);

    return 0;
}
```

And that's pretty much it. I don't know how to fix this. I don't think dealloc has the same effect. I prefer to stick to free. New information I discovered: for the sample input, I can free(*(vetor + 0)), (*(vetor + 1)) and (*(vetor + 2)), but not 3 and 4. That means the vector somehow has a problem on these two.

Comment: Your issue with `free` is generally due to some type of overrun somewhere else in your code. I'll take a look.

Comment: `malloc(n * sizeof(double));` - that would be a zero-allocation on the first iteration of your allocation loop. I don't suppose changing that to `malloc((n+1) * sizeof(double));` makes a difference, especially since you *are* reading into that location with `m = 0; m <= n` as your inner-loop init/conditional.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin
You're right!  I'm allocating nothing on that first loop. That's probably an issue. It worked! Thank you man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
for (n = 0; n < ordem; n++) {
    *(vetor + n) = malloc(n * sizeof(double));
}
```

to this:

```
for (n = 0; n < ordem; n++) {
    *(vetor + n) = malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(double));
}
```

The reason is that `n` is ZERO in the first iteration, so you are requesting `malloc()` to allocate zero bytes for you..

BTW, here is what I usually use for not making such kind of mistakes: [2d-dynamic-array-c](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/).

Output:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out
5
2.3
1.4 8.2
3.1 2.0 7.7
5.3 6.1 4.4 1.2
5.5 6.1 3.0 2.3 4.9
-0.892202112506 
-1.307537578672 1.830552610141 
-0.523015031469 -1.030647267895 1.599810684493 
0.492249441383 0.861436522419 0.076913975216 -1.399834348932 
0.584546211642 0.861436522419 -0.569163416599 -0.892202112506 0.307655900864 

4.233333333333 2.166923061753
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$
```

Comment: Beat me by `3-mins` ... `:)`

Comment: What do you mean no upvote `:)`, still working on a bit of an answer.

Comment: Oh no, your answer was the answer. That `(n + 1)` makes all the difference. The rest are just other improvements around the core issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have already received your answer, but there are several other areas where you really need to *validate* your *input and allocations* if you are going to have any confidence your code is working with actual values and not writing off into unknown parts of your hardware's memory. Always, *always*, validate user input and memory allocation. Just a few extra lines of code can help, e.g.:

```
int ordem;
if (scanf ("%d", &ordem) != 1) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (ordem)\n");
    return 1;
}
double **vetor,
       soma = 0;
int elementos, n, m;

elementos = (ordem * ordem + ordem) / 2; 
if (!(vetor = malloc (ordem * sizeof *vetor))) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
    return 1;
}

for (n = 0; n < ordem; n++)
    if (!(*(vetor + n) = malloc ((n + 1) * sizeof **vetor))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

for (n = 0; n < ordem; n++) {
    for (m = 0; m <= n; m++) {
        if (scanf ("%lf", *(vetor + n) + m) != 1)  {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (vetor + %d)\n", n);
            return 1;
        }
        soma = soma + *(*(vetor + n) + m);
    }
}
```

Good luck with your coding.